# Magento 1.7 customer/account 404 error

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I run a webstore using Magento 1.7

Before i had three store views, which i recently changed into three stores (all under the same website)

Everything but one thing works fine, the /customer/account gets a Magento 404 error on all stores. I have been reading pages up and down on the net, but i cant find the solution.

I had some issues with the admin panel earlier when i first divided the storeviews into stores, due to some mixups in the store values in MYSQL core_store. I got this working when the right store-values corresponded. Can it be something similar to this? The admin is set to value 0 in all tables.

Have anybody heard about this issue before? As i said, everything else work fine. At least everything im using in my setup

Comment: Hi, i did some testing, and it seems that new accounts work fine, its accounts that has been registered from before that gets the 404 error..Does this sound logical? Is there a fix for this in the database?

Comment: Which 404 page? http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages

Comment: Hi,, the url is .com/customer/account.. The 404 page is empty, no messages besides "404 error"

Comment: Again, per the linked article, there's numerous 404 pages in Magento, each with its own reason.  "No message besides 404 'error'" is a poor description.  Is it the default web server 404?  Magento's store exception 404? etc.

Comment: Hi again, i agree that its a poor description, however thats the way it is. Empty standard Magento page, with a 404 error message.. Im sorry, i cant describe it any differently. However, something must have happened when i divided the store-views into stores, cause the problem exists only with older accounts. New accounts work fine

Comment: Check for differences in the database customer entity tables against customers that are working and those that are not. Change suspicious values in db (or add missing ones in) for broken accounts and refresh page to see if it corrects the error.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the extended comment thread above and the [list of different 404 pages](http://alanstorm.com/magentos_many_404_pages) available in Magento, it sounds like you're getting the store exception 404 page.  This 404 page displays because something bad happened in your store, and Magento threw an Magento exception (as opposed to a plain old PHP `Exception` exception).

You can debug this my hopping to the following location

```
#File: app/Mage.php
    //...
    } catch (Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception $e) {
        require_once(self::getBaseDir() . DS . 'errors' . DS . '404.php');
        die;
    } //...
```

and adding some `var_dump` debugging code

```
    //...
    } catch (Mage_Core_Model_Store_Exception $e) {
        var_dump($e->getMessage());
        //var_dump($e); //ensire exception, may be too large to `var_dump`
        require_once(self::getBaseDir() . DS . 'errors' . DS . '404.php');
        die;
    } //...
```

This will give you the exception error text, which is often enough to solve the problem, and certainly enough to move you towards a solution.

Comment: i did this, but i am new to magento, is this supposed to show on the 404 page or the exception log? i get nothing in either place when i added the var dump

Comment: @liz var_dump will output the error to the browser window.  Add an exit after it if you're being redirected to an exception page before you can view the dumped error.  If you're not seeing it displayed, then this isn't the code path that's causing your problem.

Comment: thanks, you are correct, this isnt the problem. no code displayed after adding the exit. could this be an extension controller problem? any thoughts on how to debug that without turning off extensions one at a time?